# How to use Azure event grid to connect multiple storage accounts events to one function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid, azure-storage-account

We have a single subscription with multiple resource groups. We have multiple storage accounts in some of those resource groups. We want to watch for Blob changes in each of those storage accounts and trigger a shared function in one resource group (that is, the function exists in only one resource group).

We have successfully set up the function and an event grid subscription on a single storage account in a different resource group that successfully triggers the single central function.

Is there a convenient way to share the storage account subscriptions (via the event topic, for example)? Or do we need to set up an event subscription with topic for each storage account? In other words, if we have 5 storage accounts within a resource group, do we need 5 event subscription topics (one each)? We were somewhat hoping that there could be one subscription-topic most per resource group and each of those could/would have all the storage accounts that needed the event handler listed.

Answer (score 0):

We can use advanced filtering that will monitor only storage account events. Event type can be Resource group. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-filtering#or-and-and) is the link that will help you to understand more on this.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if the Event Grid Pricing method charges for all the Resource Group events or only the ones matching the filter (for that Resource Group's events)? I'm assuming-hoping the latter which would match the calls to the Function. In which case it may make even more sense in our case to put things at the Subscription level to monitor across all Resource Groups.